# WDK changes from 10.0.10075 to 10.0.10240

Tags: driver, windows-10, wdk

I have a kmdf driver I've been using since the beginning of Windows. I will probably be rewriting it to UMDF, but I have noticed differences in the WDK from 10.0.10075 to 10.0.10240. I include

```
usbdlib.h
ntstrsafe.h
usbbusif.h
```

These files appear in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10075.0\km

but not

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0

what happened? are they in a new file now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the files: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\km\usbdlib.h"`, `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\km\ntstrsafe.h"` and `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\km\usbbusif.h"` on my setup.

Make sure you also have the [WDK installed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/dn913721.aspx) and not only the SDK.

Comment: Oh I wonder why those didn't install but ntddk.h did. Interesting. Thanks!